# How would I go about finding out whether an address owns a specific NFT or not?

Tags: web3js, addresses, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

Can it be done simply using web3.js? Can I do it on both ERC-721 and ERC-1155 NFTs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the address of the account you want to check and a the specific id of the token you can use the `balanceOf` or `ownerOf` method of the token standards.

For ERC-1155 you would use the following code:

```js
const balance = await tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(address, tokenId).call()
const hasToken = balance > 0
```

For ERC-721 you would use the following code:

```js
const tokenOwner = await tokenContract.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call()
const hasToken = address === tokenOwner
```

References:

- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html
- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155
- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Comment: The ERC721 does have a balanceOf method aswell. So I can use that to see if an adderss has any NFT from the contract?

Comment: Depends what you want to know. If you only care if the user has any NFT then the balanceOf method of ERC-721 works. Of you require the user to have a specific NFT xou need the ownerOf function.

Comment: @Richard How is ownerOf function different from balanceOf > 0? Since it's specific with tokenId, they mean the same thing, right? Does the definition of owner mean the wallet that created the NFT whereas balanceOf means the address currently has the NFT?